# How to identify closed connected components in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, canny-operator

Given a binary image, how can I identify the closed components and remove the unclosed components?

The object inside the red rectangle is to be retained while removing other unclosed objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bwboundaries](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) to find the boundaries in the image.
Before applying it, you need to perform an image dilation to be able to identify holes:

```
I = imread('H2b_1_canny_1.jpg');
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
se = strel('disk',8);
BW = imdilate(BW,se);

[B,L,N] = bwboundaries(BW);
figure; imshow(BW); hold on;
for k=1:length(B),
    boundary = B{k};
    if(k > N)
        plot(boundary(:,2),...
            boundary(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
    else
        plot(boundary(:,2),...
            boundary(:,1),'r','LineWidth',2);
    end
end
```

[image: dilated image with highlighted hole]

Comment: This approach doesn't solve my problem. I want only the objects which are connected and closed i.e., form a cycle.